# Track next badge interface breaks when two badges earned

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface

I was really excited today as I've been working towards the fanatic badge for the last 100 days and I also got my first tag badge for Ionic4 which I am passionate about the moment.

However, the ui seems to be quite buggy.

There is a small issue with the ui where the second button is touching (see screenshot). You can't see it by default as the screenshot is when it's in the focused state.

[image]

This is from clicking the right hand button Track the next one in the screenshot above.

The click handler seems to trigger twice (there are two track next badge buttons so the selector is too vague I guess). The modal appears for me to choose my next tag, I pick but nothing happens, then I decide to abort and close the modal instead, it closes but there is another picker modal is in the background.

When I tried to click the left hand pick next badge, no popup appeared, instead it kicked me out of that ui and left me with two main stats cards:

[image]